# Calculation with Landau symbol (Big $O$)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics, solution-verification

I'm not sure about my calculations with the Landau Symbol $O$:

Let $c>0$ and $n\to \infty$. Consider:

$$\frac{1}{c\sqrt{n}+O\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\right)}-\frac{1}{c\sqrt{n}}=
\frac{O\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\right)}{\left (c\sqrt{n}+O\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\right)\right)c\sqrt{n}}=
\frac{O\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n\sqrt{n}}\right)}{\left (c\sqrt{n}+O\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\right)\right)}
$$

Now, I am not sure if I can conclude

$=O\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n^2}\right),$

since the $O$ in the denominator tends to zero compared to the other summand.

Comment: What you are wanting to do is a valid operation. I provided an alternative method that I think is a little cleaner approach, though (just my opinion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** A slightly different approach to yield your desired bound is to factor $c\sqrt n$ out of the denominator in the first fraction and use geometric series to handle the resulting term after factoring out $c\sqrt n$.

Comment: I'm not sure, if I can follow your solution. Do you mean, I can write $\frac{1}{1+O\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}$ as sum with a geometric series?

Comment: That is the right idea! But instead of $O\left(\frac{\ln n}{\sqrt n}\right )$, you should have $O\left(\frac{\ln n}{n\sqrt n}\right)$ @Philipp123

Comment: Thank you, your are correct. But how can I calculate $O(\sum \frac{\ln n}{n\sqrt n})$?

Comment: @philipp123: you can write $$\sum\frac{\ln n}{n\sqrt n}=1+O\left(\frac{\ln n}{n\sqrt n}\right)$$

Comment: @Clayton. Sum with big-O are little dangerous. For example $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k  \ne O(n)$ , it goes to $O(n^2)$. So firstly we need another letter for index inside your sum and then do you have proof?

Comment: @zkutch: sums with big-O’s aren’t dangerous. Rather, they’re straightforward. My sum above should be $\sum\left(\frac{\ln n}{n\sqrt n}\right)^k$ as it is a geometric series. From here, the big-O estimate is obvious.

Comment: @Clayton. Thanks, it's correct elaboration, this "$k$" in power clears everything, but without it, it is wrong. Now your sum is only different form of its result formula and against it we can use big-$O$. And I keep my view about  "dangerous" - it is not right place in this comment, but, if/when you'll be interested in it, I hope, I can show something more obscured.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested,

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{1}{c\sqrt{n}+O\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\right)}-\frac{1}{c\sqrt{n}}
&=\frac{1}{c\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac1{1+O\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n\sqrt{n}}\right)}-1\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{c\sqrt{n}}\frac{1-(1+O\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n\sqrt{n}}\right))}{1+O\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n\sqrt{n}}\right)}\\
&=\frac{1}{c\sqrt{n}}\frac{O\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n\sqrt{n}}\right)}{1+O\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n\sqrt{n}}\right)}\\
&=\frac{1}{c}\frac{O\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n^2}\right)}{1+O\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n\sqrt{n}}\right)}\\
&= O\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n^2}\right)\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 1):

Let me add following consideration for lovers of accuracy in proof.

By definition, taking non negative sequences, we have
$$O(g) = \left\lbrace f:\exists C > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n (n >  N \& n \in \mathbb{N}) (f(n) \leqslant C \cdot g(n)) \right\rbrace$$
So any equality, which uses O-big, and especially on both sides of equality, can be viewed as equality between sets. Also let me notice, that equality type $f=O(g)$ is quite different from type $O(f)=O(g)$. First means "$\in$", while under second we understand "$\subset \land \supset$".
There can be proved some basic properties:
$$f + O(g) = \{f \}+ O(g)=O(f+g) $$
$$f \cdot O(g) =\{f \} \cdot O(g)= O(f \cdot g) $$
Which are used, for example, on  suggested factoring out $c\sqrt n$ i.e.
$$c\sqrt{n}+O\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\right)=O\left( c\sqrt{n}+\frac{\ln(n)}{n} \right)=c\sqrt{n} \left( 1+O\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n\sqrt{n}}\right) \right)$$